# New Ubuntu install - Resolution stuck at 640 x 480

Tags: resolution, display-resolution

I recently fixed an old laptop and replaced the screen and decided to install Ubuntu. Install went fine but when I log in the resolution changes from being normal, to 640 x 480. When I try to change the resolution in settings, the only setting available is 640 x480. 
My graphics card is NVIDIA® GeForce GT 525M.

Kinda new to this so not really sure what other information would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: `xrandr` doesn't show any other settings available?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing video drivers, try to install them from cli:

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic`

Then reboot.